# How can I access numeric data that is in my HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this (It has other rows and columns as well, but using this one for now):

```
+----------------+
| Expected Total |
+----------------+
| R547 280,00    |
| R503 369,00    |
| R461 062,00    |
| R354 535,00    |
| R621 620,00    |
| R298 125,00    |
+----------------+
```

And I have the following jQuery which runs through my table and grabs the cell values I want.

```
$("#GridView2 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
  var cell2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");
  Totals.push(cell2.html());
  alert(Totals);
});
```

The problem now is, when I alert the results to my screen, I get the following output.

```
R547&nbsp;280,00 etc...
```

which obviously builds a very messy unusable array. I have been trawling the web to find a solution, but cannot find anything as yet.

(Essentially, I would like to grab only the number, with no comma and no spaces)

```
547280
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or could someone point me to a solution / the right direction?

### EDIT:

Thanks to Razor and all of you guys, I managed to get it working :) Note: I did however need to convert it to a string, then back to an int before sending it to my graph. so below is what I did if anyone ever runs into this issue.

```
        $("#GridView2 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
            var cell2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");
            var scell2 = cell2.text();
            var sscell2 = scell2.split(/[a-zA-Z,\s]/).join("").slice(0, -2);
            Totals.push(sscell2);
            //alert(Totals);

        });
        //Back to Int for Graphs
        Total1 = parseInt(Totals[0]);
        Total2 = parseInt(Totals[1]);
        Total3 = parseInt(Totals[2]);
        Total4 = parseInt(Totals[3]);
        Total5 = parseInt(Totals[4]);
        Total6 = parseInt(Totals[5]);
```

Comment: Well, using a regex you can take only the digits from the raw string, then use `parseInt()` to make it into actual number.

Comment: You can use regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"R461 062,00".split(/[R,\s]/).join("").slice(0,-2)`    will give 461062

so use this:   `var cell2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").split(/[R,\s]/).join("").slice(0,-2);`

Comment: or use this if you have multiple starting letters:  .split(/[a-zA-Z,\s]/).join("")

Comment: and  "R461 062,00".split(/[a-zA-Z,\s]/).join("").slice(0,-2) will give 461062  exactly what you need

Comment: Thanks Razor, i'm trying to go your route... Any idea why it would not be alerting anything anymore? Error on my page says the following "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'split' "... I am having a read on Google and other sites why I would be getting this error :(

Comment: Managed to figure it out, I had to make it a string first, then to the .split ... Thanks very much for your Help :)

Comment: is this happening on the "R461 062,00" too? Or only on   $(this).find("td:eq(1)"). in your page.   Try: var cell2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().split(/[R,\s]/).join("").slice(0,-2);

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex

```
var Totals = $("#GridView2 tr td:nth-child(2)").map(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are in control of populating the HTML with the data. If this is the case, I would recommend embedding an additional attribute on your DOM element. There is no need to manipulate strings if you don't have to.

```
<tr data-value="547280">
  <td>...</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Now you can just extract that attribute for the value -

```
$( "#GridView2 tr:has(td)" ).each( function() {
  var cell2 = parseInt( $( this ).data( "value" ) );
  Totals.push( cell2 );
  alert( Totals );
});
```